# UICollectionView: overlapping label on cell (storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uicollectionview, facebook-audience-network

UITableView with custom cells was created in Storyboard.

A label in a cell was connected to outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

I am setting the text of the label when creating the cell.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    if (shouldPresentNativeAds)
    {
        return self.createAdCellForCollectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
    else
    {
        return self.createRegularCellForCollectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

**The problem happens only in adCells**

```
func createAdCellForCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(NSStringFromClass(FeedAdCollectionViewCell), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedAdCollectionViewCell

    let nativeAdd = nativeAdsManager.nextNativeAd() as FBNativeAd?

    if (nativeAdd != nil)
    {
        cell.setDetails(nativeAdd!)
        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        return self.createRegularCellForCollectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

In cell:

```
func setDetails(nativeAd:FBNativeAd)
{
    if ((self.nativeAd) != nil) {
        self.nativeAd.unregisterView()
    }

    self.nativeAd = nativeAd

    if let nativeAdTitle = nativeAd.title
    {
        label.text = adTitleString
    }

    if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
        nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(self, withViewController: topController)
    }
}
```

For some reason sometimes the label is overlapping.

I added the following to cell code:

```
override func prepareForReuse()
{
    super.prepareForReuse()
    print("prepareForReuse")
    self.label.text = ""
}
```

But it didn't help.

The log is correct: prepareForReuse is always called before settings the label text. But sometimes it is overlapping. What can be done?

```
    if let nativeAdd = nativeAdsManager.nextNativeAd() as FBNativeAd?
    {
        cell.setDetails(nativeAdd!)
        return cell
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne the label is leading and trailing space to the superview and top space to image above it

Comment: What is the actual text that should be displayed in the screenshot above? Is the text shown two bits of the same text (for instance two lines that overlap instead of being one below the other), or two different texts (for instance from two different cells)?

Comment: @jcaron 2 different text. Text of the current cell and the previous one

Comment: Is the label indeed created in the storyboard, or do you add it programmatically?

Comment: Adding relevant details of your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and of you custom cell class would probably help.

Comment: @jcaron, I've updated the question

Comment: @Luda: I don't think this is the problem but could you add a check to your table view cell to check the count of your subviews, to make sure the label hasn't been added twice (for whatever reason).

Comment: Or use the view debugger to check what views are actually present. Also wondering if maybe your cell height is for some reason set to 0 and actually "spills over" the cell below?

Comment: Also while you're at it, check if the instance using `prepareForReuse()` is the same as the one you're updating the text for.

Comment: @Eendje prepareForReuse is called for sure. Couse I print "prepareForReuse" in the function and I see it in log before each ad cell is created. Why do you think the cell would add the label twice? There is no code for adding a label. It is created in the storyboard. Shouldn't it be safe?

Comment: @jcaron view debugger is a good idea. I'll try

Comment: @Luda I remember I had a similar problem a long time ago and it involved these things I just mentioned. Unfortunately I can't remember what I did to fix it :p I've read you mentioned `prepareForReuse()` is being called, but when I encountered it, the instance it was called was not the same as the one I was updating. Please check it, I'm curious :) (Check it at `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and a check at `prepareForReuse()`)

Comment: If your custom cells are defined in a storyboard, then there's no need to call `prepareForReuse()`; that's only for cells defined in code.

What do `unregisterView()` and `registerView()` do?

Comment: @Eendje, cellForItemAtIndexPath and prepareForReuse are called one after another for sure. I see it in the log. And I am updating the same instance. The problem should be in different place.

Comment: @NRitH I've added prepareForReuse to try to fix my problem. But I'll remove it now. Thank you. unregisterView() and registerView() is something that related to Facebook Audience Network. It makes the cell clickable for facebook ads